# Numerous else if statements, does this slow the site?

Tags: performance, if-statement

```
<?php if (in_category('44')) : ?>
//case
<?php elseif (in_category('26')) : ?>
//case
+50 elseif and case
<?php else : ?>
//case
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have around 50 else if statements to pull different banners for my categories around 50 of them is this fine or will this cause anything? I cant affor to create different single post templates coz i got around 1k posts and i cant manually edit them anymore.

Comment: It depends on `in_category` complexity, don't you think? It's one thing if it's essentially a comparison operator in disguise; it's completely another if it queries the DB, for example.

Comment: That's 50 separate comparisons; I'm no PHP expert but I doubt that's what you'd call optimal...

Comment: just the same code repeated  <?php elseif (in_category('26')) : ?> | <?php elseif (in_category('27')) : ?> | <?php elseif (in_category('28')) : ?> thats all i havent added anything on the elseif statement so is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that in_category is optimal. If that does a complex lookup, see if you can do it once, for example.  After that, a cascading series of else..if will not be any worse than a case statement.  Optimize it by sorting your cases so that the most likely cases are at the top, least likely at the bottom. Then if certain tests are more expensive than others, put the most expensive tests at the bottom.  If these goals are in conflict, do your best.